# How to override shapefile geometry type in OGR

Tags: python, shapefile, wfs, ogr

I'm new to ogr. I tried to copy a WFS layer to shapefile using CopyLayer but I get this error.

> ERROR 6: Geometry type of `Multi Curve' not supported in shapefiles.
> Type can be overridden with a layer creation option of
> SHPT=POINT/ARC/POLYGON/MULTIPOINT/POINTZ/ARCZ/POLYGONZ/MULTIPOINTZ/MULTIPATCH.

How can I override the geometry type? Where do I apply the SHPT option?

```
from osgeo import ogr

url = 'https://data.gov.au/geoserver/brimbank-stormwater-pipes/wfs'
wfs_drv = ogr.GetDriverByName('WFS')
wfs_ds = wfs_drv.Open('WFS:' + url)
layer = wfs_ds.GetLayer()

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
dataSource = driver.Open(shp, 0)
shp_layer = dataSource.GetLayer()
feature = shp_layer.GetNextFeature()
geometry = feature.geometry()
layer.SetSpatialFilter(geometry)
out_file = r'C:\stormwater-pipes.shp'
out_ds = driver.CreateDataSource(out_file)
out_ds.CopyLayer(layer, out_file)
```

Comment: Maybe the curve geometry test in https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/ogr/ogr_shape.py could help.

Comment: `I tried to copy a WFS layer to shapefile`, you don't need to copy the WFS data to shapefile, as this WFS server provides `SHAPE-ZIP` as one of its outputs: `https://data.gov.au/geoserver/brimbank-stormwater-pits/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.0.0&typename=brimbank-stormwater-pits:ckan_3f07bec5_99c2_491f_8d39_b6061891ebb1&outputFormat=SHAPE-ZIP&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
from osgeo import ogr

url = 'https://data.gov.au/geoserver/ows?service=wfs'
wfs_drv = ogr.GetDriverByName('WFS')
wfs_ds = wfs_drv.Open('WFS:' + url)
layer = wfs_ds.GetLayer('brimbank-stormwater-pipes:ckan_a920c6fd_2c34_4b66_adcc_101f49d5e8a8')

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')

out_file = r"D:\\stormwater-pipes.shp"
out_ds = driver.CreateDataSource(out_file)

out_ds.CopyLayer(layer, out_file, ['SHPT=ARC'])
```